# Unable to start windows 10 technical preview

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, windows-10-preview

Few time ago, I have installed windows 10 technical preview and it worked perfectly for the first two weeks. After that, it began restarting every few hours saying that **windows 10 has expired**. I have continued working on windows 10 (restarting automatically after few hours) but unfortunately now I can't start it any more. In other words, I can't boot on my windows 10.

What i have tried is to boot on ubuntu (from a flash disk) and try to repair windows 10 partion but i have faced new problem: **ALL MY DISK PARTITIONS ARE LOCKED**. I can't access any of my partitions.

I have tried also to boot on windows 10(from flash disk) and try to find a setting option to repair the windows 10 already installed and locked but nothing found.

The immediate solution is to format the whole disk(all partitions will be *ERASED* and that's so bad because I have very important files out there `:(`.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That will be one of the reasons Microsoft tell you not to use Windows 10 Preview on a live PC! If you are going to do that, you need to split your main disk in two so that your data is on the D: drive and the OS on C: so that you can reformat C: without affecting D: If you already have that, you do not need to format all partitions, only the C: drive where W10 is installed.

Comment: Your license expired, there isn't anything you can do, you should have taken the notices to heart

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Technical Preview, as the name suggests, is not for production. I think it's your fault, that you can't access your files.

What I have read, Windows 10 automatically locks if you don't update it, but I don't know how to do it, because I'm not using it.

The only thing that comes to my mind is accesing the Windows 10 partition offline from Ubuntu or other liveCD.

Comment: I have already tried to access it from ubuntu but it didn't work.

Comment: What error did it gave you?

Comment: @ChakerMallek: There's no reason your files should be inaccessible from within Linux unless your drive is defective or you've messed up the partition table or MFT somehow.